# using R to copy files

Tags: r, file, copy

As part of a larger task performed in R run under windows, I would like to copy selected files between directories. Is it possible to give within R a command like `cp patha/filea*.csv pathb` (notice the wildcard, for extra spice)?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way (shy of shelling-out), but something like the following usually works for me.

```
flist <- list.files("patha", "^filea.+[.]csv$", full.names = TRUE)
file.copy(flist, "pathb")
```

**Notes:**

- I purposely decomposed in two steps, they can be combined.
- See the regular expression: R uses true regex, and also separates the file pattern from the path, in two separate arguments.
- note the `^` and `$` (beg/end of string) in the regex -- this is a common gotcha, as these are implicit to wildcard-type patterns, but required with regexes (lest some file names which match the wildcard pattern but also start and/or end with additional text be selected as well).
- In the Windows world, people will typically add the `ignore.case = TRUE` argument to `list.files`, in order to emulate the fact that directory searches are case insensitive with this OS.
- R's `glob2rx()` function provides a convenient way to convert wildcard patterns to regular expressions.  For example  `fpattern = glob2rx('filea*.csv')` returns a different but equivalent regex.

Comment: I think the pattern should be `"^filea.+[.]csv"`.

Comment: @Marek: right you are!  Also, in particular in the Windows world, peopole will typically want to add the argument `ignore.case = TRUE`.  I edited accordingly, thanks.

Comment: you can use ?glob2rx to convert from wildcards to regexes.

Comment: @Edurardo Leoni: yes, you can.  The nice, if only occasionally unsettling, thing about R is that you keep discovering ways of doing things.  It's the first I heard about glob2rx in R; I typically write my regexes longhand (which btw for the globbing patterns isn't that hard), but yeah, glob2rx() works.  I'll add this to the notes in the answer.

Comment: If you are using this with intention to copy and replace files, then please **do not forget**  to add `overwrite = TRUE` inside  `file.copy()`! Lost an hour debugging this.

Answer (score 12):

You can

- use `system()` to fire off a command as if it was on shell, incl globbing
- use `list.files()` aka `dir()` to do the globbing / reg.exp matching yourself and the copy the files individually
- use `file.copy` on individual files as shown in mjv's answer

Comment: never heard of `dir`. It's _exactly_ identical to `list.files`... strange to have both

Comment: 'dir' is older, but less intutive.

Answer (score 0):

For fellow script kiddies:

```
mainDir<-getwd() #so it creates the file wherever your working directory is
  subDir<-"name_of_my_new_sub-directory"
  dir.create(file.path(mainDir, subDir), showWarnings = FALSE)
  setwd(file.path(mainDir, subDir))
```