# Copy files from few directories

Tags: r, file, directory, rstudio

I am trying to create a code which copies all folders/files from an existing folder to another (the origin folder has files and more folders that contains files/folders...)

My idea was to do something like this:

```
files <- list.files (Dir.origen)

for (i in files)
{  
  if (!file.info (paste(Dir.origen, i, sep = "/"))$isdir) 
    file.copy (paste(Dir.origen, i, sep = "/"), Dir.dest)
  else dir.create (paste(Dir.dest,i,sep = "/"))
}
```

and insert the same `for` loop in `else` statement, and more loops inside.

My question is if there is a way to copy an entire directory.

I am also interested in source this code every time I create a new project in RStudio.

As RStudio creates a new directory for an empty project my objective is to fill this directory with all content I need.

Comment: Why not use [system()](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/system.html)? For example, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11395548/680068)

Comment: @zx8754, unfortunately R language is the only one I "know" so I've asked to see if there is an R solution to this before to start learning another possibilities that would take me much more time.

Comment: This answer might be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2384621/3730796

Comment: Thank's for your comments, it helps me to find a right direction to research. I posted a working code in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out an answer, it is easier then it seems:

```
Dir.origen2 <- gsub("/","\\\\", Dir.origen) # Directiories must use backslashes
Dir.dest2 <- gsub("/","\\\\", Dir.dest)

comando <- paste0 ("xcopy ", Dir.origen2, " ", Dir.dest2, " /e /i /y")
system(comando)
```

where `/e` is for copy all the directories (including empties), `/y` for don't ask overwriting of documents and `/i` to create a new directory if Dir.dest do not exists (I guess).