# Copy Many Images to New Folder Using Recursion

Tags: r, bash, terminal, parallel-processing

I'm trying to copy more than 50,000 images within multiple folders into one single folder using Terminal (Mac OSX El Capitan). I've managed to achieve this with a few images using:

```
cp `find . -name "*.jpg"` resultsFolder
```

However, I get an error (argument list too long) when trying to run this code on 50,000 images. How do I overcome this error, and perhaps speed this process up (perhaps using GNU parallel?).

I'm also hoping to run this from within R using `system()`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For speedup: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124527/speed-up-copying-1000000-small-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because the `ARG_MAX` (or analogous in libraries other than `glibc`) is being triggered.

Inefficient, copying files one at a time:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec cp {} /foo/bar \;
```

If you have GNU `cp`, you can leverage `+` with the `-exec` action of `find`:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec cp -t /foo/bar {} +
```

Comment: double-quoting the files as, `"{}"` would preserve white-spaces in file names, and also a `-v` flag for verbose would be better for readability. +1

Comment: OK I'm not quite following. I keep getting an error (cp: illegal option -- t). Just to confirm, I cd to the parent folder containing the multiple folders with images. Then I use find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec cp -t /foo/bar {} + Though I'm not quite following the /foo/bar section? Do I need a folder called foo within the parent folder, and within that a folder called bar. Sorry, perhaps I'm a bit dense? Thanks so much for everyone's help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Inian Apparently `+` will not work with `cp {}` as the command line is built by appending. Also `{}` handles filenames with whitespaces.

Comment: @Ross That means you don't have GNU `cp`, use the first command. `/foo/bar` is just an example, replace it with the destination folder you want to copy the files into.

Answer (score 1):

An R implementation based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384517/using-r-to-copy-files#2384621) (you can replace `"/tmp"` with a result folder of your choice).

```
flist <- list.files(".", "*.jpg", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
file.copy(flist, "/tmp")
```

If there are any duplicated file names, they will not be copied. 
R can tell you what files where not copied if 
you store the result of the copying operation (Similarly you can replace `tempdir()` by the directory of your choice).

```
copysucceeded <- file.copy(flist, tempdir())
```

Show files which could not be copied

```
flist[!copysucceeded]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
find . -name "*.jpg" | xargs -i cp {} resultsFolder
```

Comment: `xargs` with cp` is not needed as `find` itself can do the copy/move action using the `-exec` option.

Answer (score 0):

there is exactly one awesome way to do this:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t resultsFolder
```

this is always faster for > 1 file than `find -exec cp {}` or `find | xargs -i cp {}`, and handles any kind of characters in filenames. for large files, it is only slightly faster than the alternatives, because most of the time is spent actually copying. for many tiny files, it can be an order of magnitude faster.

test: copy 3422 ~20k files (OSX Yosemite, Late 2013 MacBook Pro, 2.6 GHz i7, 16 GB RAM, 500GB SSD):

```
find -exec cp {}         29.445s
find | xargs -i cp {}    22.800s
find | xargs cp -t        0.599s
```